# Serving static content from spring cloud config-server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

All of our spring cloud microservices make use of Spring REST docs to generate documentation and serve it from `/docs/index.html`. This works well.

Not so for the config server. I'm running it embedded with `@EnableConfigServer`. I've moved the config root to `/config` with `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` and can see that it has indeed been relocated both in the config server startup logs and the Eureka `metadataMap` for the config server (nice bit of integration there).

The documentation `index.html` is bound into the spring boot jar at the correct `/static/docs/index.html` location but it is not reachable on the config server's port.

I must be missing something straightforward here. What do I need to do to re-enable `/static` as a root for static resources in the jar?

Comment: I created project that works with the configuration you've described. https://github.com/spencergibb/config-server-static-files You'll need to share a project that recreates the problem.

Comment: It's working now. I think the issue was with me running the project from within Eclipse where the docs were not on the classpath. From a terminal it works just fine. Thanks for your help.